# First row hidden when table view appears while search controller is active

Tags: ios

I'm using UISearchController with a UITableViewController. When I have a search in progress, and I select a row in the table to go to the detail view, and then go back to the table view, the first row of the table is hidden behind the search bar.

I can scroll the first row back into view, but then it just pops back behind the search bar when I let go of the scroll. So frustrating!

In viewDidLoad I have:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
mainTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Removing definesPresentationContext = true solves the problem, but I need that to prevent the search bar from showing up if the user segues to other view controllers.

I've spent hours searching for a solution and trying different ways to fix the problem.

Is there any way to set the first row of the table so it is below the search bar when the table view re-appears?

I tried setting definesPresentationContext = true in prepareForSegue, but that did not work.

Comment: push your table or collection view down by the height of the search controller on top using uiview animation and layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem.

1. Do not set definesPresentationContext = true
2. In prepare(for:sender:), add the following. This keeps the search active, but prevents the search bar and keyboard from appearing on the view controller being segued to.

   ```
   searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
   searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
   ```
3. In viewWillAppear, add the following. This makes the search bar visible when the view controller with the search controller comes to the top of the navigation stack. The first row of the table is positioned properly below the search bar.

   ```
   searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
   ```
4. In willMove(toParentViewController:), add the following. This cancels any active search, preventing the search bar from appearing on the view controller coming to the top of the navigation stack.

   ```
   if parent == nil {
       searchController.isActive = false
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```